# GCC inline assembler: CPSR is not a value register name

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly

I'm using GCC inline assembler to read the CPSR ARM register the following way, and getting the following error.

```
uint32_t register_cpsr = 0u;

asm volatile("mrs %0, cpsr" : "=r"(register_cpsr) :);
```

```
/tmp/ccSxUIyF.s:159: Error: unknown or missing system register name at operand 2 -- `mrs x0,cpsr_c'
```

Does anybody know what name should I use for the CPSR register?

Comment: You are building for aarch64 and cpsr is for aarch32.  aarch32 has no registers named 'x0'.

Answer (score 1):

"artless noise" is correct.

CPSR was split in multiple register for ARM64, and DAIF is the AMR64 register to enable/disable interruptions.

See: [How to read PSTATE in AARCH64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73717613/how-to-read-pstate-in-aarch64)